# Eclipse CDT and Debug/Release Modes

Tags: c, eclipse-cdt, release-mode, debug-mode

I just got a simple "Hello, World!" C program to build and compile in the [Eclipse CDT plugin](http://eclipse.org/cdt/). When you go to create a new C project, or when you go to set up a Run Configuration for an existing C project, Eclipse gives you the ability to specify either a Debug or Release Mode.

I am wondering what the difference is betwee these two modes. Obviously, Debug Mode is some kind of development mode that might not optimize things and take longer to build/run. But being new to C it's tough for me to actually understand what sort of configurations/param are Debug vs Release. Shockingly, the CDT documentation does not make any mention of Debug vs Release Mode whatsoever!

Can someone give me a **concrete** use case of something that might be a Debug Mode configuration, but *not* included in Release Mode? And, vice versa, something that would be included in Release Mode, but excluded in Debug Mode?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally, the additional flag `-g` is passed to `gcc` in debug build. It tells gcc to inlude debug info to the program. It's not possible to debug programs built without this flag.

Another debug flag is `-O0`, which disables optimization. When you step through an optimized program, it will often jump to unexpected line of code, which makes it harder to debug.

Comment: Thanks @basin (+1) - how do I configure exactly what flags get set in each mode? How do I tell what flags Eclipse's Run Configurations are setting? Thanks again!

Comment: @smeeb I think they're set in project properties, not run config